# Querying an Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to get matching values from two different tables of an Access Database. I was wondering if it were at all possible to get values from a column where the cell begins with "SN" and leave all the rest of the data out. Here's what I have so far.

```
        String filePath = textBox1.Text;

        con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath);
        con3 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath);



        if ((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == "CGA0112")
        {
            try
            {
                string end = "ENDDATE";
                string qual = "CGA0112";
                string start = "START";

                ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT* FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] Where KEYWORD = '" + end + "'AND QUALIFIER = '" + qual + "' AND EXPRESSION = '", con); // ISSUE AFTER EXPRESSION= 


                ds.Clear();
                ad.Fill(ds);

                con.Open();
                ad.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                ad3.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT* FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] Where KEYWORD = '" + start + "'AND QUALIFIER = '" + qual + "'", con3);
                ds3.Clear();
                ad3.Fill(ds3);

                ds.Merge(ds3); //merges the two datasets together


                win1.frm1 = this;
                win1.Show();

                con3.Open();
                ad3.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con3.Close();

            }
```

I guess I just want to add some code after the EXPRESSION area but I'm not too sure where to begin. I just want it to read something like AND EXPRESSION = startswith("SN"). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not that I want to suggest a completely new way of thinking, but have you heard of the [EntityFramework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework)?

Comment: @gunr2171 I have not actually

Comment: `AND EXPRESSION LIKE 'SN%'` (May be `*` instead of `%` - can't remember) (you can also reuse a single connection ...)

Comment: Not that this really solves your problem quickly, but I would suggest taking a look at it. It solves your problem in about 1 line, and eliminates SQL injection (which your code is prone to).

Comment: you want to use substring i would imagine to only search the first 2 letters

Comment: @gunr2171: Entity Framework doesn't work with Access databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `like` as follows:

```
"SELECT * FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] Where KEYWORD = '" + end + 
"' AND QUALIFIER = '" + qual + "' AND EXPRESSION LIKE 'SN*'"
```

However, as someone mentioned in the comments, I think you should definitely look into a framework, maybe something like [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net), which is pretty awesome. There are also a handful of libraries that extend Dapper to make it even easier to get going, like [this one](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions).

**Edit:** See comments - `'SN%'` should be used with OleDb, not `'SN*'`

Comment: I know this code works, but it is an excellent example of [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx). What happens if `end` is equal to `'; drop table AC_ECONOMIC --`?

Comment: If `end` and `qual` were coming from user input, I would agree with you, but in this case they're defined by user2607468 right above the query. That said, there are better ways to construct queries, like by adding parameters via `SelectCommand.Parameters.Add()`.

Comment: A handful of people keep trying to edit 'SN*' to be 'SN%'. However, * is the wild card character for MsAccess, not %.

Comment: With OleDb the wild card must be `%`, not `*`.  This issue with MS Access has been discussed many times here on SO.  Here are 2 examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193350/like-command-problem-using-oledbreader-and-ms-access and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166907/ms-access-sql-any-reason-why-like-does-not-work